# How to access value from outer query in inner query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * FROM events e LEFT JOIN venue v ON v.id=e.venueid 
CROSS JOIN (select (((5*sum(rating = 5))+(4*sum(rating = 4))+(3*sum(rating = 3))+(2*sum(rating = 2))+sum(rating = 1))/count(*)) rating 
from feedbacks where boxid = **e.boxid**) r 
WHERE e.startdate = CURDATE() AND e.starttime >= CURTIME() 
LIMIT 10;
```

I can't access **e.boxid** inside the subquery. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `GROUP BY` on `boxid` to bring it outside the subquery and then join it with `events` table on `boxid` column like this:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    events e
        LEFT JOIN
    venue v ON v.id = e.venueid
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        boxid,
            (((5 * SUM(rating = 5)) + (4 * SUM(rating = 4)) + (3 * SUM(rating = 3)) + (2 * SUM(rating = 2)) + SUM(rating = 1)) / COUNT(*)) rating
    FROM
        feedbacks
    GROUP BY boxid) r ON e.boxid = r.boxid
WHERE
    e.startdate = CURDATE()
        AND e.starttime >= CURTIME()
LIMIT 10;
```

You could also use correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT e.*,
  v.*,
  (SELECT (((5*SUM(rating = 5))+(4*SUM(rating = 4))+(3*SUM(rating = 3))+(2*SUM(rating = 2))+SUM(rating = 1))/COUNT(*)) AS rating
  FROM feedbacks f
  WHERE f.boxid = e.boxid
  ) rating
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN venue v
ON v.id           = e.venueid
WHERE e.startdate = CURDATE()
AND e.starttime  >= CURTIME() LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to this uses a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT e.*, v.*,
       (SELECT (((5*sum(rating = 5))+(4*sum(rating = 4))+(3*sum(rating = 3))+(2*sum(rating = 2))+sum(rating = 1))/count(*)) as rating 
        FROM feedbacks f
        WHERE f.boxid = e.boxid
       ) as rating
FROM events e LEFT JOIN 
     venue v
     ON v.id = e.venueid 
WHERE e.startdate = CURDATE() AND e.starttime >= CURTIME() 
LIMIT 10;
```

In this situation, because the `WHERE` clause filters out many records (presumably), the correlated subquery could be much more efficient than the `GROUP BY`.  This is especially true if you have an index in `feedbacks(boxid)`.

Comment: This approach more efficient  just takes 1.9 ms group by take longer. Thank you :)